# What’s the difference between 960.gs/Blueprint and LESS?

Tags: css, blueprint-css, less, 960.gs

Ultimately, I like to code my own CSS. I hate it when I have to conform to someone else's naming conventions... especially when they have no real meaning. However, I am attracted to the fact that a mobile site is pretty much ready to go with a framework.

Now, I've seen several comparisons between 960.gs and Blueprint, but LESS is never involved in those debates. Why not? Am I missing something? To me, it seems that LESS does pretty much the same basic things.

http://lessframework.com/

Anyone care to discuss?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LESSFramework is a css grid system that supports responsive webdesign principles. Thats the area of webdesign that strives to make one website design to support all browsers from mobile to large screen. The lessframework grid system adapts it's layout to the available screen real estate.

That's where it really differs from classic grid systems like 960.gs or blueprint.

LESS Framework is fairly new too, that's probably why you don't see it that much in reviews or comparisons.

If you want to compare them you'll have to figure out what you really need from a css framework.

- **960.gs** is a pure grid layout system, nothing more ... but the most widely used one.
- **Blueprint** is a grid system that goes a little further, it also offers typography and form styling
- **LESSFramework** is a grid system that's only really usefull if you are aiming to create a [responsive layout](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). If you are not you'll probably be better off with 960.gs

Comment: Do you like it? Recommend it?

Comment: Unless you are ready to invest extra time in creating a layout that's responsive you'll be better off with 960.gs which is imo the most widely used grid system. i've updated my anwser to elaborate a little further

Answer (score 3):

[960.gs](http://960.gs/) and [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) are grid systems.

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) is a CSS pre-processor (aka `LESScss`).

Comparing it to them makes no sense, they do totally different things.

---

Update:

You seem to be talking about something different from [LESScss](http://lesscss.org/), a grid system called [LESSFramework](http://lessframework.com/).

I am leaving this answer here so people reading this question will see the different projects and what they are.

Comment: The very first line on the LESS website: "Less Framework is a CSS grid system for designing adaptive web sites." ... from that statement and many others, LESS is a grid system. I think it's a very valid question and it makes sense. I used the word "basic" because that's my question. If you want to get deep on the subject, yes, I'm sure they are quite different. But for my "basic" needs, my question remains.

Comment: @dcolumbus - You must be looking at a different site than I am.

Comment: @dcolumbus - http://lesscss.org/ is the one I mostly hear mentioned when `LESS` is discussed.

Comment: You are probably mixing up LESScss which indeed is the css preprocessor (much like SASS) and [LESSFramework](http://lessframework.com/) which is a responsive-webdesign grid system.

Comment: @ChrisR - I have only seen the use of only `LESS` in the context of `CSS` with `LESScss`. I have never seen the `LESSFramework` mentioned simply as `LESS`.

Comment: @ChrisR That's it. I'm talking about why on earth would anyone use the same name as another related piece of software?